# PowerMockito with RoboElectric private method not mocked

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Trying to get PowerMockito going here for unit testing on android with RoboElectric.  I want to call a public method in a test and verify some behavior, but I want to change the response of a private method in that class.  This sample:

```
public class TestPrivate {

    public String doTest() {
        return test();
    }

    private String test() {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

I want to run a test that called doTest, but use PowerMockito to change what test() returns.  My attempt below does not work, test() Returns "FOO" when i'd expect my test to return "BAR"

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestPrivate.class)
public class WebSocketClientTest extends TestCase {


    @Test
    public void testConnect() throws Exception {

        TestPrivate spy = PowerMockito.spy(new TestPrivate());
        doReturn("BAR").when(spy, method(TestPrivate.class, "test"));
        String response = spy.doTest();
        assertEquals("BAR", response);

    }
}
```

couple of things:

Using the RoboElectric Test Runner seems ok with PowerMockito 1.6

Here is my gradle import

```
  androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
  androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-mockito-release-full:1.6.0'
```

Thanks in advance, there are other posts about this but none of them work and are years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@PrepareForTest` annotation probably isn't being run, since you're using the Robolectric test runner and not the PowerMock runner. The example doesn't show any Android code -- if this really is a standalone test, then switch to the PowerMock runner. If you really do use Android code in the test you'll have to look into how to properly initialize PowerMock without the annotation.

Comment: Thanks Tom - yeah I didn't understand the runner.  This procedure let me run the test with the roboelectric runner: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1058